# DBD::SQLite fastest way to insert multiple rows

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

I have tried 3 different approaches to inserting multiple (over 500) rows into a SQLite table. Counter-intuitively, approach 3 below is the fastest. I would have assumed approach 2 would be the fastest because it uses a "prepared" statement handle. But my third approach - inserting 500 rows at a time (500 is apparently the max allowed in SQLite) - is way faster.

Am I missing anything? Should I continue with the 500 approach, or is there another way?

note: the below code is not my actual code, I just wrote it here for example purposes and has not been tested.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dsn = "DBI:SQLite:dbname=db";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"","");

open my $data_file,"<","data.txt"; # 3 integer fields per line

APPROACH_1:
while (<$data_file>) {
    my @fields = split "\t";
    my $insert = join ",", @fields;
    $dbh->do("insert into table values ($insert)";
}

APPROACH_2:
my $sql = "insert into table values (?,?,?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
while (<$data_file>) {
    my @fields = split "\t";
    $sth->execute(@fields);
}

APPROACH_3:
my @inserts;
while (<$data_file>) {
    my @fields = split "\t";
    my $insert = '('.join(",",@fields).')';
    push @inserts, $insert;
    if (@inserts == 500) {
        my $insert_500 = join ",", @inserts;
        $dbh->do("insert into table values $insert_500";
        undef @inserts;
    }
}
# insert leftovers
```

Comment: I'm not surprised by your results. I haven't used SQLite much, but at least with MySQL, batched inserts of more than just a few rows are much faster than inserting each row individually. This makes sense: every insert requires talking to the database, which has a certain amount of overhead associated with it.

Comment: Also, for an even greater number of rows, importing a CSV using the DBMS's native import capability is probably even faster (MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` is much faster than batched imports for my particular application when inserting > ~100 rows). SQLite [has a CSV import command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv), but I'm not sure if you can use it via DBI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See in the example below where autocommit is set to 0

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=pedro.lite","","",
    {PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 0}) or die "Can't connect";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{INSERT INTO purchases VALUES(?,?,?,?)})
    or die $dbh->errstr;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $sth->execute( split /\|/ );
}

$dbh->commit() or die $dbh->errstr;

__DATA__
Pedro|groceries|apple|1.42 
Nitin|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00 
Susie|groceries|cereal|5.50 
Susie|groceries|milk|4.75 
Susie|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00 
Susie|fuel|gasoline|44.90 
Pedro|fuel|propane|9.60
```

This disables the commit until all records are inserted. In practice, you may not want to wait to commit if there is a lot of inserts - perhaps every 5000 inserts or whatever you feel is best. By not committing, if there is an error or computer shutdown, then you will only have created the number of records at the last commit - a difficult situation.

Comment: had not thought about autocommit. will try tomorrow thanks.

Comment: I finally got around to testing this. you were right. disabling autocommit is really really fast. thank you.

Comment: @beasy Glad to be of help. Glad that solved your problem.